# Ubuntu system problems

Tags: 16.04, system

I obviously have some problems with my system which I cannot figure out.
Some of aspects:

- after starting the OS I get the message that some internal error was found
- when I open *Ubuntu software* no installed items are listed
- also I have problems with firefox
- after apt-get update there are also some errors with updating ubuntu security

Maybe there is any standard routine to check if there are any problems?

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Maybe it would be reasonable to reinstall the sytem for a higher version? I wanted to give anyway more space (as I use Ubuntu alongside with Windows10).

best alex

Comment: There is a standard routine to read error messages, not ignore them saying "some error", "some problem". You can always fix "some error" by "doing something".

Comment: What does `dmesg -l err` show? This command will print out the error messages listed by the kernel. This is a good place to start for the "internal error".

Comment: you might also check`/var/log/syslog` for special issues. As an example for Firefox you might run `grep -i firefox /var/log/syslog` (and narrow ur search by timestamp, error message ... and the like).

Comment: @PSA: `after dmesg -l err` I get  17 ACPI errors. The first one is `ACPI Error: Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20170531/dsopcode-235)`

Comment: Also, after running `sudo apt-get update` there are 3 _failed_-messages: the first one is `E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: @Würgspaß by running `grep -i firefox /var/log/syslog` there are also several messages, the first one is  `com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Webhistory.Firefoxbookmarks[2100]: /usr/share/unity-scopes/scope-runner-dbus.py:24: PyGIWarning: Unity was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Unity', '7.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.`

Comment: For Firefox I tried once what they advice: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-bookmarks-and-history-will-not-be-functional?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=The+bookmarks+and+history+system+will+not+be+functional&utm_source=inproduct

Comment: The ACPI errors are indicative of power regulation code in your motherboard's BIOS/UEFI that works with Windows but does not work with Ubuntu (see [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/acpi-error-what-means-4175605357/#post5707423)). This may affect sleeping, resuming, or hibernating on the laptop.